# Compile and run C code using clang API

Tags: api, clang, llvm, jit

I would like to use the clang/llvm APIs to compile a c-function, defined in a string and immediately execute it.
Something like:

```
void main() {
  std::string codestr = "int foo(int bar) { return bar * 2; }"

  clang::??? *code = clang::???.compile(codestr);

  int result = code->call("foo", 5);
}
```

I am looking for tutorials, but what I found so far does not quite match my goal or does not work, because it refers to an outdated version of LLVM.
Currently, I am using LLVM 3.5.

Does anyone have a good tutorial at hand?

Answer (score 4):

I followed [this blog post](http://fdiv.net/2012/08/15/compiling-code-clang-api) with good results. The clang API has changed, so you may have to make adjustments. With LLVM 3.6.1, I got good results with the following code:

```
llvm::Module* compile(const char* filename) {                                                   
        clang::CompilerInstance compiler;                                                     
        clang::CompilerInvocation* invocation = new clang::CompilerInvocation();              
        llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticIDs> DiagID(new clang::DiagnosticIDs());    
        auto diagOptions = new clang::DiagnosticOptions();                                    
        clang::DiagnosticsEngine Diags(DiagID, diagOptions,                                   
                new clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter(llvm::errs(), diagOptions));                 
        std::vector<const char *> arguments = {filename};            
        clang::CompilerInvocation::CreateFromArgs(*invocation,                                
                &*arguments.begin(), &*arguments.end(),                                       
                Diags);                                                                       
        compiler.setInvocation(invocation);                                                   
        compiler.setDiagnostics(new clang::DiagnosticsEngine(DiagID, diagOptions,                                   
                new clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter(llvm::errs(), diagOptions)));                                                      
        std::unique_ptr<clang::CodeGenAction> action(new clang::EmitLLVMOnlyAction());        
        compiler.ExecuteAction(*action);                                                      
        std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module> result = action->takeModule();                          
        llvm::errs() << *result;                                                              
        return result.release();                                                              
}
```

I was very careless with the pointers, so its very possible there's a memory leak or a double free (although it didn't crash).

I couldn't figure out how to take the source from a memory buffer, so I dumped it in a temporary file using `mkstemp`.

I didn't get around to executing the result, but I think you can follow @michael-haidi's response, or check out the LLVM Kaleidoscope tutorial ([This is the JIT chapter](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl04.html)).

Comment: I am having trouble recreating your code, do you have an updated version? or possible the whole code itself so that i can follow up with it?

Comment: I don't have access to that code. However, the complete code is not relevant, it just moves the input around and dumps it to a file, or reads the output and dumps it. I only wrote this one version, and as I said in the post, I never got around to executing it (I needed this for some optimisation tests, but had to move to a different project).  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using MCJIT because the old JIT infrastructure will be removed in a further release.
I can't point you to a full tutorial and cannot promise that the API hasn't changed since the blog post but [here](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/07/using-mcjit-with-kaleidoscope-tutorial.html) you'll find a guide how to use MCJIT with the Kaleidoscope example from LLVM and thats it. Examples and tutorials are hard to find for LLVM/Clang. However, I suggest trying it and maybe you can document your journey with a short example.

The [Julia](http://julialang.org/) project also uses MCJIT for jit compilation of C++ code inside of the Julia lang. Maybe you can peek at the code and find out how the use MCJIT.

Good luck ;)