# C/C++ to LLVM IR API - Is there a programmatic way to compile?

Tags: c++, c, llvm

I was looking into the following use case but could not find a straight answer.
Does LLVM have an API to do this:

1. Starting with a set of C functions and associated data structures.
2. Compile it to an LLVM IR object (e.g. a Module)

I see it is possible to use the clang frontend to emit LLVM IR into a bytecode file and then possibly read this into a LLVM module. Or use the LLVM tools to build an IR (e.g. as in [LLVM: simple example of a just-in-time compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982070/llvm-simple-example-of-a-just-in-time-compilation)).

However, these are not exactly what I am looking for. I wanted all to happen in memory,
no calling external commands, dealing with files, and I don't need to design a new
language and use the LLVM stack to create the IR from it. The source code is in C.

So, the question is whether there is an API to write a program that will do 1 & 2 and
produce an IR object that I can plug into an On-Request-Compilation code.

I thought libclang would do it, but it seems designed for other purposes, maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Read this [blogpost](https://blog.audio-tk.com/2018/09/18/compiling-c-code-in-memory-with-clang/)

Comment: LLVM does not contain programming language parsers, neither for C nor for any other languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27226940/8925535

Comment: yes, LLVM does not have parsers, but libclang might do the job. It looks like the answer is in the blogpost above